# Kubernetes credentials for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

After adding the kubernetes plugin on Jenkins, what kind of credential info do I need to put so that I can manage the kubernetes cluster. Also, where do I get the credential info on the master node?

Thanks!
Phil

Comment: You need to provide more information. What did you try, what issues did you encounter. What tutorial have you tried? Did you read documentation? https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes or this https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Kubernetes+Continuous+Deploy+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

You didnt precise your question, if you are using On-Prem or Local, however in internet you can find many good tutorials about Jenkins plugin.

The best tutorial can be found on [jenkins plugin doc](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes). You can find there information how to configure Minikube, GKE, AWS.

> In Jenkins settings click on add cloud, select Kubernetes and fill the
>   information, like Name, Kubernetes URL, Kubernetes server certificate
>   key, ...
>
> If Kubernetes URL is not set, the connection options will be
>   autoconfigured from service account or kube config file.
>
> When running the Jenkins master outside of Kubernetes you will need to
>   set the credential to secret text. The value of the credential will be
>   the token of the service account you created for Jenkins in the
>   cluster the agents will run on.

You should also read [this](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Kubernetes+Continuous+Deploy+Plugin) and this [github tutorial](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-cli-plugin).

If you need more detailed help, please edit your question and provide more information.